# coffeescript and angular directive

Tags: coffeescript, angular.js

I feel this is deeply inelegant, but I really want the option of classical inheritance in the future. How could this be written better. FYI animation here is from [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) if you are curious.

```
class Modal

    angular.element(document).ready =>
        @modalElem   = document.getElementById 'modal'
        @overlayElem = document.getElementById 'overlay'

    @isOpen = false

    @getWindowDim : ->
        return dim =
            height : window.innerWidth or document.documentElement.clientWidth
            width  : window.innerHeight or document.documentElement.clientHeight

    @openModal : (attrs) ->

        unless @isOpen

            @isOpen = true

            width   = attrs.width 
            height  = attrs.height
            content = attrs.content 

            wDim    = @getWindowDim()           

            @modalElem.style.width      = 0
            @modalElem.style.height     = 0

            @overlayElem.style.display  = 'block'

            TweenLite.to @modalElem, 0.75, 
                width       : width
                height      : height
                marginTop   : (height/-2)
                marginLeft  : (width/-2)
                opacity     : 1
                ease        : Back.easeOut
        @

    @closeModal : ->

        if @isOpen

            @isOpen = false

            TweenLite.to @modalElem, 0.33,
                width       : 0
                height      : 0
                marginTop   : 0
                marginLeft  : 0
                opacity     : 0
                ease        : Back.easeOut
                onComplete  : =>
                    @overlayElem.style.display = 'none'
        @

modal   = angular.module 'modal'

modal.directive 'openmodal', ->
    return (scope, element, attrs) ->
        element.bind 'click', ->
            Modal.openModal attrs   

modal.directive 'closemodal', ->
    return (scope, element, attrs) ->
        element.bind 'click', ->
            Modal.closeModal()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I'd recommend against creating a class. You *may* want classical inheritance in the future, but right now it's not necessary. Premature optimization rarely benefits anyone. Besides, if you do want classical inheritance later, it's pretty trivial to convert the code.

I'd just write it as simply as possible for now, and see what I'll actually need later:

```
do -> # wrap in an IIFE
  # simple local variables
  isOpen      = false
  modalElem   = null
  overlayElem = null
  modal       = angular.module 'modal'

  angular.element(document).ready ->
    modalElem   = document.getElementById 'modal'
    overlayElem = document.getElementById 'overlay'

  open = (attrs) ->
    return if isOpen # return early
    isOpen = true

    options =
      opacity:    1
      ease:       Back.easeOut
      height:     attrs.height
      width:      attrs.width
      marginTop:  attrs.height / -2
      marginLeft: attrs.width / -2

    modalElem.style.width  = 0
    modalElem.style.height = 0
    overlayElem.style.display = 'block'
    TweenLite.to modalElem, 0.75, options

  close = ->
    return unless isOpen # return early
    TweenLite.to modalElem, 0.33,
      width:      0
      height:     0
      marginTop:  0
      marginLeft: 0
      opacity:    0
      ease:       Back.easeOut
      onComplete: ->
        overlayElem.style.display = 'none'
        isOpen = false # moved this here, so it flips when the modal's fully closed


  modal.directive 'openmodal', ->
    (scope, element, attrs) ->
      element.bind 'click', -> open attrs

  modal.directive 'closemodal', ->
    (scope, element, attrs) ->
      element.bind 'click', -> close()
```

If you're compiling this as a single file with CoffeeScript's default IIFE wrapper, you can skip the `do ->` and indentation; it'll be added automatically.

---

If you don't want to take the approach above, here are some tips for your current code:

Using explicit `return` is only necessary if you want something *other* than the last evaluated expression to be returned. In you open/close functions, it'd be beneficial to simply return early (like I do in the code above) instead of having a big `if` branch.

Also, a neat trick:

```
getWindowDim : ->
  return dim =
    height : window.innerWidth or document.documentElement.clientWidth
    width  : window.innerHeight or document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

can be written as

```
getWindowDim : ->
  height : window.innerWidth or document.documentElement.clientWidth
  width  : window.innerHeight or document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

The `return` is implicit, there's no need for a variable assignment, and CoffeeScript will automatically make an object.

Comment: actually it turns out `getWindowDim` is not consumed at all! In your finished example, please replace `height` and `width` with the version from `attrs` and I will accept your answer. +1

Comment: @Fresheyeball Whoops - fixed now

Comment: It's a trend I don't really like in coffeescript (and ruby). People tends to write as less characters as possible and it alters the readability of the code. I'm not sure that getting rid of the `return`really helps clarity. When the `return`keyword is present, it's clear that the function is meant to return something. It might be personal, but I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one out there.

Comment: @jackdbernier I know what you're saying. But it also depends on how you view the code overall. If you regard it as more functional (as you can with ruby and js/cs), variables and function calls become interchangeable; a function just _is_ its return value - and all functions always return something, even if it's `undefined`. (Obviously, this looks better in languages - like ruby - where you can leave out the `()` in calls). Naming is key, though; nouns for pseudo-variable functions, verbs for _function_ functions (i.e. the above should be called `windowDimensions` without the `get` prefix)